# Crystal Reports Text Rendering Issue

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I upgraded Crystal Reports for VS2008  to CR for VS2010 on one of my clients machine. But now there is a text rendering issue. Some letters are overlapping on each other of some text objects. Is this a known issue or did I miss something.

Comment: How is the text formatted? Rich Text, HTML?

Comment: It's rich text. It works well in designer. Problem is in client's machine.

Comment: When you upgraded, did you uninstall the old runtime first before installing the new one? Also, did you install the latest service packs for CR?

Comment: Firstly I was unable to uninstall old version. I installed the new version along with old version. But later I uninstalled both versions and re-installed the new version. But the problem was not solved.

Yes I installed latest service pack